# Gigya doesn't logout of social session

Tags: ios, gigya

I have Gigya logging in properly using social login. However when I try to logout using [Gigya logout], when I tap on my Google button on the login screen, it logs me back in without asking for my Google credentials.

How can I get it to ask me again for my Google credentials?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you've configured Google+ native login, then your app has already been authorized by the user.  Because there is an active Google+ session for the Google+ app on the device, when Gigya request authentication from the native app, it then detects that there is an active session and that the app is already authorized.  Because of this, the user is automatically logged in without being prompted for credentials.  This behavior is expected and by design. If you want to force the user to authenticate every time then this needs to be done as follows:

When making your call to `[showLoginProvidersPopover:providers:parameters:...]`  ensure that you are including the parameter ["forceAuthentication"](http://wikifiles.gigya.com/SDKs/iPhone/doc/html/Classes/Gigya.html#//api/name/loginToProvider:parameters:completionHandler:) with a value of YES as outlined in the documentation for loginToProvider:

For example:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
     @"forceAuthentication":@YES
};
[Gigya showLoginProvidersDialogOver:self
    providers:@[@"facebook", @"twitter", @"googleplus"]
    parameters: params
    completionHandler:^(GSUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Login was successful
            }
        else {
            // Handle error
            }
}];
```

Comment: I agree that an auto-login is the proper normal flow, however if I include a log out option to the user, then it shouldn't automatically log in to the social provider.

Comment: It isn't automatically logging the user into the social provider.  The user is **already** logged into the social provider through the Google+ app.  The user only has to grant permissions to Google+ for your app once.  The call to `[Gigya logout]` does not log the user out of the Google+ app; only out of Gigya on your app.  Google has specifically prohibited outside applications for altering the active session in the Google+ app because it could be used maliciously.

Comment: Gigya still requests authorization from G+ when the user "logs in". If there was no active session in the Google+ app, then the user would be prompted for credentials to log in.

Comment: Testing this now and find that it doesn't work as advertised for Google. Once I have logged in with google, I can no longer get the google login to show. Seems to work as advertised for Facebook and Yahoo, but not Google.